# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) in project

Tags: ios, swift

I just started Swift and I am having problems. 
I want pagination, and I coded this.

model:

```
struct MoreListAppand {
    var MoreNoticeListModel : [MoreNoticeListModel] = []

    mutating func addTask(task: MoreNoticeListModel){
        MoreNoticeListModel.append(task)
    }

}

struct MoreNoticeListModel {
    var pageInfo : PageInfoFragmentModel? = nil
    var totalCount : Int = 0
    var edges: [NoticeInfoModel] = []

    mutating func map(MoreNoticeListModel item: NoticeList){

        self.pageInfo = nil
        let pageData = item.pageInfo
        var pageModel = PageInfoFragmentModel()
        pageModel.map(item: pageData.fragments.pageInfoFragment)
        self.pageInfo = pageModel

        self.totalCount = item.totalCount

        print("NoticeList totalCount == ", self.totalCount)
        self.edges.removeAll()
        for edge in item.edges! {
            var edgeModel = NoticeInfoModel()
            edgeModel.map(NoticeInfoModel:(edge?.fragments.edgesInfoFragment)!)
        self.edges.append(edgeModel)
        }
    }
}

struct PageInfoFragmentModel {
//    var hasNextPage : Bool << If I do not comment, an error will appear.(Missing argument for parameter 'hasNextPage' in call)
//    var hasPreviousPage : Bool
    var startCursor : String = ""
    var endCursor : String = ""

    mutating func map(item:PageInfoFragment) {
//        self.hasNextPage = item.hasNextPage
//        self.hasPreviousPage = item.hasPreviousPage
        self.startCursor = item.startCursor
        self.endCursor = item.endCursor
    }
}

struct NoticeInfoModel {
    var cursor : String = ""
    var id : String = ""
    var type: noticeType = .URGENT
    var title: String = ""
    var createdAt: String = ""

    mutating func map(NoticeInfoModel item: EdgesInfoFragment){
        self.cursor = item.cursor
        self.id = item.node.id
        self.type = noticeType(rawValue: item.node.type.rawValue)!
        self.title = item.node.title
        self.createdAt = item.node.createdAt

         print("NoticeList title == ", self.title)
        print("NoticeList type == ", self.type)
    }
}
```

and

```
 @objc func myAction(_ sender : AnyObject) {

        //sever connect
        MoreAPI.shared.getNoticeList(first: 10, last: 0, offset: 0, after: "MjAxNy0xMi0wNVQxNzo1MDozMVo=", before: ""){

            [unowned self] (noticeItemLists) in

            self.noticeAddListDataModel?.addTask(task: noticeItemLists)
            let indexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row:((self.noticeAddListDataModel?.MoreNoticeListModel.count)!), section:0) << this is error line
            self.noticeListTable.reloadData()

        }
    }
```

- `self.noticeAddListDataModel`defined here

```
class MoreNoticeViewController: UIViewController {
    var noticeAddListDataModel : MoreNoticeListModel? = nil
}
```

- why PageInfoFragmentModel want "hasNextPage" parameter argument..?
- I got error

  > "let indexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row:((self.noticeAddListDataModel?.MoreNoticeListModel.count)!), section:0)" line.

I do not know why I get this error....

Answer (score 0):

Follow naming convention, which is for `variables` `camelCase`.

```
struct MoreListAppand {
    var MoreNoticeListModel : [MoreNoticeListModel] = []

    mutating func addTask(task: MoreNoticeListModel){
        MoreNoticeListModel.append(task)
    }

}
```

here var `var MoreNoticeListModel` is `Struct` name, change it to var `moreNoticeListModel`.

**1. why PageInfoFragmentModel want "hasNextPage" parameter argument..?**

That is a `model` written by someone who added that `variable` that is why it is there, we won't be able to tell about that. If there is no use of those variables `comment` them.

**2.**

`noticeAddListDataModel` doesn't have any reference to `MoreNoticeListModel` instead it is of same type, you can't get count property from a model.

Maybe this is what you need ? `self.noticeAddListDataModel?.totalCount` or   `self.noticeAddListDataModel?.edges.count`.

Comment: `noticeAddListDataModel` difine ```class MoreNoticeViewController: UIViewController { var noticeAddListDataModel : MoreNoticeListModel? = nil}```

Comment: Update answer with few points, you need to fix couple of things here.

Answer (score 0):

The error Missing argument for parameter 'hasNextPage' in call states that you have a variable defined in the struct and not initialized. Since it is not initialized, you have to pass its value in the constructor call,i.e. where you are calling **PageInfoFragmentModel()**, you have to call **PageInfoFragmentModel(hasNextPage: )**. This constructor is defined by default by swift, if no constructor is defined. So to remove the bug, either you give it a value or make it an optional or pass its value in initialization. Read this : https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html for more info.